# SQL Can I Use "OR" / "AND" in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql

I am new to databases and wanted to know if I could use a statement similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table Where Name = "abc" or "xyz" or "pqr";
```

I am aware that this doesn't work and I need to find entries in tables where the name may be any one of these.

Thank you

Comment: As has already been multiply answered, this is pretty easy. Without wanting to be too harsh, can I suggest reading a good introductory book on SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Column name again so:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
Where Name = "abc" 
OR Name = "xyz" 
OR Name = "pqr";
```

But in this case its much better to do an `IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
Where Name IN ("abc","xyz","pqr");
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a relational database (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc...), but you need to specify the column name each time, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
Where Name = 'abc' or Name = 'xyz' or Name = 'pqr';
```

It would be more efficient to write it using the `IN` statement, however:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
Where Name IN ('abc', 'xyz', 'pqr');
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to use with `AND` and `OR` is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
Where Name = "abc" 
  or 
      Name = "xyz" 
  or 
      Name = "pqr"
```

Note that you need to qualify the column name for every clause.

Though you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
Where Name IN ("abc", "xyz", "pqr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table Where Name IN ('abc','yz','pqr')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Field IN ('abc','xyz');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Field = 'abc' OR Field = 'xyz';
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is each side of the OR operator must be an expression that evaluates to a boolean (true or false).

This is a corrected version of your statement:

> `Select * From Table Where Name = 'abc' or name = 'xyz' or name = 'pqr'`

You could also write it using the IN clause:

> 

```
Select * from Table Where Name in ('abc', 'xyz', 'pqr')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. It is of great help :)